# Given $A_8$, find a cyclic subgroup and a noncyclic subgroup, both with order 4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups, permutation-cycles

### Question: Given an alternating group $A_8$, find a cyclic group with order 4 and a non-cyclic group with order 4.

So I don't know how to start this one since I'm confused how it could have a cyclic group with order 4 when it would result to three transpositions, making it an odd permutation.

Regarding the non-cyclic group, I also have no idea. Do I just map out an element to another element randomly? Or is there a technique for this?

I'd appreciate for any enlightenment for this one.

Comment: $4$-cycles are not the only permutations which have order $4$. Try to think of a different cycle structure.

Comment: Would a product of disjoint cycles, one with order 4 and the other a transposition work? Because it would be an even permutation and the lcm would be 4? If this is acceptable, may I ask how do I know which numbers to use? Do I map any element to another element randomly or should it have a pattern? For example, an element maps to its product with 2 (2 maps to 4, 3 goes to 6, and so on)?

Comment: Yes, this will work. Not sure I understand your question though. You can take any permutation with this cycle structure.

Comment: Thank you. My question is quite trivial but for example, could I simply put (1327)(45) which are just numbers I have randomly placed with no pattern as long as they are in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}?

Comment: Yes. Distinct permutations with the same cycle structure have the same order, so you can pick any such permutation.

Comment: @cme yes! The specific numbers don’t matter at all, they are just names.

Comment: As a hint for the second part, you can start with $(12)(34)$ and see if you can work from there. Also, you know the group has to be the Klein $4$-group, so each (non-trivial) element should have order $2$.

Comment: @Milten can you elaborate?

Comment: Would {e, (12)(34), (14)(32), (13)(24)} be correct?

Comment: @cme Yes, that works! (Also e.g. $\{e,(12)(34),(34)(56),(12)(56)\}$ would work.)